# Intensive Writing Rolling Window Postgresql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database which is intensively written (continuous flow of 50000 rows/minute) where almost all the values are inserted one by one in the same table. Before I used to have a regular database with one table  but the table was getting really big and queries took too much time.

Now I have designed a Rolling Window database. I have a parent table *measurements* and a set of child tables *meas_1, meas_2...meas_7*. In *meas_1* I insert the values of today, in *meas_2* the values of yesterday and so forth. When the a next day comes I create a new *meas_x* child table, I drop the oldest table *meas_7* and I set a function that is triggered when I insert data to *measurements* (parent table) so that values are redirected to *meas_x* (new child table). By doing this I can take advantage of the contraint_exclusion when querying and I can also drop the oldest table (*meas_7*) without need to run a vacuum operation to free space in the disc.

The trigger and the function looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_measurements_trigger 
                BEFORE INSERT ON measurements 
                FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE measurements_insert_trigger();'


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION measurements_insert_trigger() 
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN
            IF ( NEW.timestamp >= d1_0 AND NEW.timestamp < d1_1 ) THEN
                INSERT INTO "meas_1" VALUES (NEW.*);
            ELSEIF ( NEW.timestamp >= d2_0 AND NEW.timestamp < d2_1 ) THEN 
                INSERT INTO "meas_2" VALUES (NEW.*); 
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO "CatchLostRows" VALUES (NEW.*); 
            END IF; 
            RETURN NULL; 
        END; 
        $$ 
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please note that *d1_1 > d1_0 = d2_1 > d2_0*

I have a Python script that is taking care of updating all the settings in the Rolling Window Database. I have another Python script in charge of inserting all the data.

My problem is that this operation takes too much time and I cannot deal with such a high input rate. I insert rows one by one and since the function is executed  in a per row basics it takes to much time (that is my guest). How could I improve the performance of my Rolling Database script? Would it be better to set a rule instead?

Comment: Can't you make the Python script insert directly into the children? That would avoid the trigger and maybe allow efficient bulk insert. Without more details, especially in the Python insert script, it is hard to go beyond just guessing.

Comment: The Python insert script does the following: 1) Read string with non-formatted data 2) Extract relevant information (id, value, timestamp) 3) Insert relevant information (one row at the time) to table  *measurements* (parent). I could change the step 3 by inserting data to child table but I would have if statement depending on time (checking timestamp). I thought that writing this if statements in SQL would be more efficient/fast than in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not expensive to make Python decide in which child it should insert. I'm assuming there are 7 children, one for each week day.

```
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
cursor = conn.cursor()

insert_query = """
    insert into %(child)s (id, value, "timestamp")
    values
    (%(id)s, %(value)s, %(timestamp)s)
"""
timestamp = datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
insert_dict = {
    'child': AsIs('meas_' + str(timestamp.isoweekday())),
    'id': 1,
    'value': 1,
    'timestamp': timestamp
}

cursor.execute(insert_query, insert_dict)
conn.commit()
```

The next step would be to evaluate some form of caching of the input stream for subsequent bulk insert. Where does the data come from? How?

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. I have removed the SQL trigger/function and I have modify the insert Python scrip to decided in which child table to insert the new data. So far it seems to be working fine. The stream of data comes form a message broker in chunks of raw text. I process each chunk in a way that produce several inserts (depends on the size of the chunk). As it is right now it is more convenient for me to insert them one-by-one. If in the future I experiment delays in the insertion I will consider your proposal of bulk insert.